# Disable Dataflow/Beam logging on FileIO.matchAll()

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a Dataflow job written in Java (Beam version 2.43.0, Java 11), which reads messages from Pubsub that contains path to Cloud Storage files.

Due to high volume of messages, especially during start of the job, Dataflow logging complains with:

```
Throttling logger worker. It used up its 30s quota for logs in only 24.528s
There was a high rate of log messages from the job and some of them were not sent to Cloud Logging.
```

[image: Throttling logger worker]

The above is caused by below:

[image]

These logs came from a particular function, I suspect `FileIO.matchAll()`, which automatically writes a matched file path to Dataflow logging.

Here is the piece of Beam code (`gcsFilePath` is `PCollection<String>`)

```
gcsFilePath
  .apply(FileIO.matchAll())
  .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
```

Is there a way to disable this, without changing the current Cloud Logging settings (bec I need the logging for other purposes)?

Comment: Have you gone through  these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#LogControls),[link2](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.41.0/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowWorkerLoggingOptions.html) and [link3](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/disabling-fine-graining-dataflow-worker-logs-000004272)?.